# Creating a Unified Support Box by Combining Different Support Level

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have a question that I just can't figure out myself. Even though I have some  finance background, programming is completely new to me, so bear with me.

How can I combine two horizontally calculated support level, that use different Periods for their calculation into a single large support box, given the following conditions:

1. They should not exceed a certain vertical distance from each other, a variable called "tolerance" with a default value of 0.003 (0.3% price difference)  in my case.
2. Both supports exist (are plotted) simultaneously for at least one candle.

When these conditions are met, the box should start from the initially plottet beginning of the first support (regardless of whether it is the upper or lower support) and extend to the plottet end of the second support.

In other words, if both conditions are met, both participating supports are considered valid, and a box will be drawn over the entire area between the two supports, starting from the leftmost drawn support point to the rightmost drawn support point.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for a solution !

I have tried all possible combinations with a drawBox(condition, y1, y2, color) function, but I am having difficulty including the past support values in the box. Tried with box.set_right(drawBox, bar_index - period).

However, since either the green or red support line always comes first, and sometimes the upper support comes first and sometimes the lower support comes first, I am unable to solve the problem satisfactorily. I am struggling to create a reusable support box with the appropriate box.set_right() and box.set_left() functions.